# rails has one through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

i have a user model with fields name and sex. And user can have an one-to-one association called "spouse" with another user, the association must be between a male user and a female user.

with the help of [railscasts self-referential-association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association) i create the basic association like this,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :spouse_list
  has_one :spouse, :through => :spouse_list

  has_one :inverse_spouse_list, :class_name => "SpouseList", :foreign_key => "spouse_id"
  has_one :inverse_spouse, :through => :inverse_spouse_list, :source => :user
end

class SpouseList < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :spouse, :class_name => "User"  
  belongs_to :user  
end
```

SpouseList has fields :spouse_id, :user_id,

above association can create many rows for single user and shows the first row if access spouse by @user.spouse_list.spouse.name

How can i restrict between a male user and a female user?

Comment: Would it be at all possible to re-write your question as it's pretty difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: need to make a one-to-one self association, and the association can be made only to restricted type. something like, Any registered user can choose his partner, user can be male or female, male can only make female as his partner and female can only make male as her partner.

Answer (score 1):

finally i made one-to-one self association for the below condition,

"User can have an one-to-one association called "spouse" with another user, the association must be between a male user and a female user"

added a field spouse_id to user model and created a self association with custom validation,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :spouse, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :base_user, :foreign_key => "spouse_id"
  has_one :base_user, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :spouse

  validate :validate_spouse_gender

  private
  def validate_spouse_gender
    errors.add(:spouse_id, 'could not be with same sex') if spouse && spouse.sex == sex
  end

end
```

Now a male user A can only make association as spouse with another user B, if B is of gender  female.

hope it helps someone.